# How can types and values be validated / enforced for Elixir structs?

Tags: elixir

How can types and ranges of values be validated / enforced for Elixir Structs?

e.g. During Struct creation, throwing an error if invalid types/values are handed in

- lat should be numerical and between -90.0 and +90.0
- lon should be numerical and between -180.0 and +180.0

```
defmodule Location do
  @enforce_keys [:lat, :lon]
  defstruct lat: 0, lon: 0
end
```

There was some discussion here with [@JoséValim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588267/jos%C3%A9-valim), but not clear what the outcome was
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elixir-lang-core/U_wdxEqWj_Y

Comment: As one way to go, you could wrap the creation in a separate function which would validate the data and return either the new struct or an error.

Comment: but then you would spread the logic (and tests) which do the validation across all of your codebase .. not DRY.
If  this can be done in the `Location` module, then it can be also tested just there.

Comment: Just put it in the `Location` module, just add a function called `build` or something. I said nothing about creating a separate module for it.

Comment: thank you @JustMichael, but you if provide `build`, couldn't others just work-around this by calling `%Point{12.3,123.4}` directly? That seems to be a pretty big lose end..

Comment: Others could also bypass a constructor in OO--if your end-users refuse to work with the tools you've laid out for them there's little you can do to prevent that. It seems as if you're still thinking of the OO approach which can be very counter-productive in FP languages.

Comment: thank you, yes @OnorioCatenacci I'm still ramping up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether you are looking for a lifetime guarding / type guarantees, **it is impossible**. Structs are [bare maps underneath](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/structs.html#structs-are-bare-maps-underneath):

```rb
defmodule Location do
  @enforce_keys [:lat, :lon]
  defstruct lat: 0, lon: 0
end

loc = %Location{lat: 0, lon: 0}
is_map(loc) #⇒ true
```

even more, one might simply create a `map` with `__struct__` key set to the atom, denoting the struct name, and voilà:

```rb
loc_str = %{__struct__: Location, lat: 0, lon: 0}
#⇒ %Location{lat: 0, lon: 0}
```

or use [`Kernel.struct/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#struct/2), that [does not check anything](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/1451797b919c03557f8c9c0468edd5a40c852600/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L1976):

```rb
struct(Location, [lat: 0, lon: 0])
#⇒ %Location{lat: 0, lon: 0}
```

---

That said, one should not treat `struct` as a first-class citizen in Elixir types hierarchy. It’s a map with an additional field `__struct__` set.

In Elixir we commonly use [Typespecs](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/typespecs-and-behaviours.html) and [`dialyzer`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/dialyzer.html) for static code analysis for that purpose.

Comment: thank you @mudasobwa! I need to learn more about Typespecs and dializer.

Answer (score 5):

Like @mudasobwa said, you can't make these guarantees at every step in Elixir since it's a dynamically typed language. But you can do it when building a struct in a helper function.

Here's an example from [one of my projects](https://github.com/sheharyarn/geo-bounds/blob/master/lib/geo_bounds/coordinate.ex):

```ex
defmodule Location do
  defstruct [:latitude, :longitude]

  @moduledoc "A struct representation of geo-coordinates"

  @latitude  %{max: +90,  min: -90}
  @longitude %{max: +180, min: -180}


  @doc "Return a new struct for given lat/longs"
  def new(long, lat) do
    validate_latitude!(lat)
    validate_longitude!(long)

    %Location{latitude: lat, longitude: long}
  end


  # Raise error if latitude is invalid
  defp validate_latitude!(lat) do
    case is_number(lat) && (lat <= @latitude.max) && (lat >= @latitude.min) do
      true -> :ok
      false ->
        raise Location.InvalidData, message: "Invalid value for Latitude"
    end
  end


  # Raise error if longitude is invalid
  defp validate_longitude!(long) do
    case is_number(long) && (long <= @longitude.max) && (long >= @longitude.min) do
      true -> :ok
      false ->
        raise Location.InvalidData, message: "Invalid value for Longitude"
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

The Python people have the word "pythonic" to describe idiomatic Python code. I wish we had the same for Elixir ("elixirish"?). With this in mind, I tried to make @Sheharyar's solution a little less verbose and more functional, omitting all the conditional constructs:

```
defmodule Location do
  @moduledoc "A struct representation of geo-coordinates."

  defstruct [:longitude, :latitude]

  @doc "Return a new struct for given lat/longs"
  def new(long, lat) do
    valid_latitude?(lat)
    valid_longitude?(long)

    %Location{longitude: long, latitude: lat}
  end

  # Raise error if latitude is invalid
  defp valid_latitude?(lat) 
    when is_number(lat) and (-90 <= lat) and (lat <= +90),
    do: :ok

  defp valid_latitude?(_lat),
    do: raise "Invalid value for latitude; valid: -90..+90."

  # Raise error if longitude is invalid
  defp valid_longitude?(long)
    when is_number(long) and (-180 <= long) and (long <= +180),
    do: :ok

  defp valid_longitude?(_long),
    do: raise "Invalid value for longitude; valid: -180..+180."
end
```

Of course, there is almost always room for improvement:

```
defmodule Location do
  @moduledoc "A struct representation of geo-coordinates."

  defstruct [:longitude, :latitude]

  @doc "Return a new struct for given lat/longs"
  def new(long, lat) when
    is_number(long) and (long in -180..+180) and
    is_number(lat) and (lat in -90..+90),
  do: %Location{longitude: long, latitude: lat}

 def new(_, _),
   do: raise "Valid latitudes: -90..+90; valid longitudes: -180..+180."
end
```